shadcn Select component - select option from available SelectContent options following fetch
When a user types in a postcode in defendantPostcode field, I want to query my API, retrieve a postcode ID and, in the subsequent Select field, select the option with the matching ID.
I succesfully fetch the Area / Area.id, and the Select component works by itself (if I select an option and submit the form, I can see the area ID).
When I however try to set the Select component value using the ID I receive from the API, it is no longer captured by the form - however, in the browser, it is set to the correct option.
How do I select the option from the dropdown, given an ID I receive from the API?
I believe the issue lies here, in the value:
<Select

  value={props.selectedArea ? props.areaOptions?.find(option => option.id === props.selectedArea?.id)?.id : field.value}

  onValueChange={(value) => {
    onAreaChange(value);
    field.onChange({ target: { name: 'defendantArea', value } })
  }}
  >

I've commented my code for context:
// My interfaces for reference.
// Area is just id, area_name and a short_code (area code)
// areaOptions is an array of Areas

interface Area {
  id: string;
  area_name: string;
  short_code: string;
}

interface AreaProps {
  selectedArea: Area | null;
  setSelectedArea: Dispatch<SetStateAction<Area | null>>;
  areaOptions: Area[];
}

interface AreaSelectProps extends AreaProps {
  areaOptions: Area[]; // area options is an array of Areas pass into this component
  defendantPostcode: string;
}

// My API
const backendUrl = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL;

// My component

const AreaSelect: React.FC<AreaSelectProps> = (props) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchAreaOptions = async () => {

      // When user types in a postcode into previous field, 
      // it'll do a query against it and retrieve matching area code
      // 
      // I enter in "ab" - http://localhost:8000/api/v1/area/?search=ab
      // and I succesfully get the data -
      // [
      //   {
      //     "id": "1",
      //     "area_name": "Aberdeen",
      //     "short_code": "AB"
      //   }
      // ]
      // 
      // This is then used below by setSelectedArea to selectedArea.
      // It appears to correctly set the item in Select menu below
      // - but this isn't updating the form values

      // onSubmit - {
      //   "claimReference": "",
      //   "defendantName": "",
      //   "defendantAddress1": "",
      //   "defendantAddress2": "",
      //   "defendantTown": "",
      //   "defendantCounty": "",
      //   "defendantPostcode": "ab", <- this is what I typed in
      //   "defendantArea": "", <- this isn't actually being captured by the form,
      //                           although it's "chosen" in Select menu
      //   "hceOfficer": ""
      // }

      if (props.defendantPostcode) {
        const areaCode = props.defendantPostcode.match(/^([A-Za-z]+)/)?.[1];

        if (areaCode) {
          const response = await fetch(`${backendUrl}/api/v1/area/?search=${areaCode}`);
          const data = await response.json();

          if (response.ok) {

            // If an area is returned, setSelectedArea
            if (data.length === 1) {
              props.setSelectedArea(data[0]);
            }

          } else {
            console.error('Error fetching area:', data.error);
            props.setSelectedArea(null);
          }
        }
        // rest excluded for brevity
      }
    };

    fetchAreaOptions();
  }, [props.defendantPostcode]);


  // Handle changes to Select / when user changes selection
  // 
  // This works fine. If I select an Area from the Select menu, it will update the Select menu and updates the form values

  // onSubmit - {
  //   "claimReference": "",
  //   "defendantName": "",
  //   "defendantAddress1": "",
  //   "defendantAddress2": "",
  //   "defendantTown": "",
  //   "defendantCounty": "",
  //   "defendantPostcode": "",
  //   "defendantArea": "1", <- ID is set as expected
  //   "hceOfficer": ""
  // }

  const onAreaChange = (value: string) => {
    const selectedArea = props.areaOptions.find(option => option.id === value);
    if (selectedArea) {
      props.setSelectedArea(selectedArea);
    } else {
      props.setSelectedArea(null);
    }
  }

  return (
    <FormField
      control={props.control}
      name="defendantArea"
      render={({ field }) => (
        <FormItem>
          <FormControl>

            {/* The issue is here.
            
            If I type in postcode "ab" the correct Area is retrieved and displayed in the Select menu below, but when I submit the form,
            the defendantArea isn't updated.

            onSubmit - {
              "claimReference": "",
              "defendantName": "",
              "defendantAddress1": "",
              "defendantAddress2": "",
              "defendantTown": "",
              "defendantCounty": "",
              "defendantPostcode": "ab", <- typed in
              "defendantArea": "", <- displayed in Menu ("Aberdeen (AB)") but not captured by form
              "hceOfficer": ""
            }

            If I then change the value in Select menu, it's captured:

            onSubmit - {
              "claimReference": "",
              "defendantName": "",
              "defendantAddress1": "",
              "defendantAddress2": "",
              "defendantTown": "",
              "defendantCounty": "",
              "defendantPostcode": "ab",
              "defendantArea": "2", <- I have manually selected option 2 / "St Albans (AB)" from the menu and it's fine
              "hceOfficer": ""
            }

            */}

            <Select
              
              // I have tried just using field.value, functions, or statements, etc.
              // I believe I'm just displaying selectedArea rather than hooking into this properly to set the value

              defaultValue={props.areaOptions?.find(option => option.id === field.value)?.id}
              value={props.selectedArea ? props.areaOptions?.find(option => option.id === props.selectedArea?.id)?.id : field.value}
              
              // This works I believe
              onValueChange={(value) => {
                onAreaChange(value);
                field.onChange({ target: { name: 'defendantArea', value } })
              }}

            >
              <SelectTrigger>
                <SelectValue placeholder="Select an area" />
              </SelectTrigger>

              <SelectContent>
                {props.areaOptions && props.areaOptions.map((option) => (
                  <SelectItem key={option.id} value={option.id}>
                    {option.area_name} ({option.short_code})
                  </SelectItem>
                ))}
              </SelectContent>

            </Select>
          </FormControl>
          <FormMessage />
        </FormItem>
      )}
    />
  );
};

export default AreaSelect;

